# PHP form is not sending data into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am new in php. I have been trying to enter data into MySQL through PHP form but unfortunately it is not working. I have used post method. Kindly help me

```
<html>
    <body>
    <form action=zain.php method="post">
        category <input type="text" name="product_category"><br />
        <br />
        Name: <input type="text" name="product_name"><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" id = "go" name="submit" value="Go">
    </form>
    </body>
    <?php
    $user = 'root';
    $password = 'zz224466';
    $db = 'Zain';

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', $user, $password, $db);

    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    echo "connected";

    mysqli_select_db($conn, "zain");


        $sql = "INSERT INTO product WHERE product_id=1 (product_category , product_name) VALUES('$_POST[product_category]','$_POST[product_category]')";

        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        mysqli_close($conn);


    ?>
    </html>
```

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: You're also using the same POST array in your VALUES.

Comment: Wrong syntax of insert query `INSERT INTO product WHERE product_id=1 ` What is `where` doing here

Comment: INSERT does not have a WHERE clause http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html - INSERT ... SELECT does http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html or INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Plus, you're open to some serious SQL injection here.

Comment: Oh, nice *Stealth edit*. So tell us, is this going to be an incremental experiment??

Comment: I have removed where clause but still not working

Comment: any error are you getting?

Comment: You use `'$_POST[product_category]','$_POST[product_category]'` product category two time in your insert query. Where is your `product_name`??

Comment: @Saty *Yep!* - I told them that [here...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948062/php-form-is-not-sending-data-into-mysql#comment57627453_34948062) already ;-)

Comment: Ohh i miss that point!! @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Saty Nonetheless, that would have/should have entered the same value for both. They're not telling us the whole story.

Comment: As @Fred-ii- said, your code contains vulnerabilities from hackings like SQL injections

Comment: Plus what happen when you come first time in your page?? It insert blank entry . No condition to check either form is submit or not!!

Comment: None of you have fixed my problem but I don't know why are you downvoting my question

Comment: Because, all your comments about ***"Not working"***, tells us nothing. I told you what to do already: **Check for errors** [20 minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948062/php-form-is-not-sending-data-into-mysql#comment57627415_34948062). Oh, I guess I forgot to ask, or someone else did that: *"any error are you getting? – Pathik Vejani 15 mins ago"*

Comment: Plus, you're using this whole code inside the same page and probably/most likely getting ***empty data*** inserted into db but haven't told us that. Am I right on this? @ZainFarooq soon as your page is loaded, it enters empty data. Am pretty sure I'm right about this and probably entering characters that MySQL is complaining about also.

Comment: I think your last comment has some piece of solution for me @Fred-ii

Comment: @ZainFarooq Glad to hear I was of help.

Comment: But you all have wasted my time and rating too

Comment: simply You should have pointed out error here... thats all

Comment: @ZainFarooq Honestly, you haven't given us much to go on. A good question gets a good score, and we've been playing the guessing-game for the most part here. Guess this is a lesson that you should do proper error-checking and report what is given from that to those trying to help you. We have not at all wasted your time, more like you're wasting our like this. Don't complain when people are helping you - for *free*.

Comment: @ZainFarooq actually Zain, you should have improved on your question to tell us what was happening while you were executing this code. Nobody knew, only you did. And I was the one who figured out what was happening where you are. You're behind your computer, we're not ;-) You have my answer below also. amongst a few. You can now continue with your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides other answers given, your entire code is inside the same page and you are most likely getting empty data inserted in db as soon as the page is loaded.

Therefore, you need to use a conditional statement (checking for empty data input) and pre-assigning variables first and using your submit button's name attribute.

I.e.:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if( !empty($_POST['var1']) && !empty($_POST['var2']) ){

    $var1 = $_POST['var1'];
    $var2 = $_POST['var2'];

    // execute your SQL
     }

}
```

---

From comments:

Plus, you're using this whole code inside the same page and probably/most likely getting empty data inserted into db but haven't told us that. Am I right on this? @ZainFarooq soon as your page is loaded, it enters empty data. Am pretty sure I'm right about this and probably entering characters that MySQL is complaining about also. – Fred -ii- 5 mins ago

I think your last comment has some piece of solution for me @Fred-ii – Zain Farooq 2 mins ago

@ZainFarooq Glad to hear I was of help. – Fred -ii- 2 mins ago

---

- Another option would be to seperate your HTML form from your PHP/SQL and also using a conditional statement as outlined in my answer above.

Plus, you were using the same 2 POST arrays in your VALUES `VALUES('$_POST[product_category]','$_POST[product_category]')`, as I already outlined in comments. One of those should have been `$_POST[product_name]`.

You may also be entering characters that MySQL could be complaining about, such as apostrophes, etc. I.e.: `Joe's Bar & Grill`. Therefore you would need to escape your data, something you should be doing anyway.

- Checking for errors against your query would have told you about that, should it contain syntax errors.
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Another thing that could also have an effect are the column types and lengths. The columns must be long enough to accommodate for the data being inserted. If you are entering a string length that is greater than your column's length, MySQL will fail silently.

---

Footnotes:

You don't need this `mysqli_select_db($conn, "zain");` and can be safely removed, since you already declared all 4 parameters in:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', $user, $password, $db);
```

Comment: Thanx God.. You have found error. But I have wasted my time and sucked my mind here..

Comment: @ZainFarooq We all like to help people here Zain. But when we don't know what is not going on, or what is happening, then one must try to guess sometimes lol. I would look at the positive side of this though, being a lesson learned. We all learn, even I do continue learning, we are not perfect, we're only human. Don't feel so bad, but please include important information in a question to let everyone know the results you get when executing code, if it's "empty data", an error, or both, it can be anything. Again, only you know what is going on over where you are, not us ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: I have switched to web for a long time. I was just testing my code to start project. I have also used this code before but this time it was not working as I had also confusion. Therefore I posted whole code before you and I didn't know any additional information that i could share with you. Hope you got my point.. God bless you

Comment: @ZainFarooq You have the option to mark the question as solved. You don't have to, but this will inform everyone that the question was solved. Otherwise, it will remain as being unanswered. *Cheers*

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of things to address with this code. Firstly, as already in the comments, you previously had a `WHERE` clause. Insert queries doesn't use this, as you are inserting in a new row - not updating one.

Furthermore, you are using `$_POST[product_category]` inside your SQL-statement. Note that the superglobal `$_POST` is an array, and as such, you need to properly index whatever you're trying to retrieve from that array, so it would instead be `$_POST['product_category']` (note the single-quotes).

In addition, your code is [vulnerable to SQL-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), and since you are already using `mysqli_`, you should apply *prepared statements* to your code.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO product (product_category , product_name) VALUES (?,?)";
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $_POST['product_category'], $_POST['product_name']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Usage of [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) would've alerted you when something is wrong, so please apply this to your code - it makes troubleshooting a lot more easier when you know what exactly is wrong.

Comment: I have used this but not working

Comment: "*Not working*" is not very specific. I'm not really up for playing the famous guessing-game. If you apply error-reporting to your code, you'll be able to tell what's failing. Come back with an error-message, and we can work from that.

Comment: ...indeed. As I told them [here...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948062/php-form-is-not-sending-data-into-mysql#comment57627415_34948062) already ;-) @Qirel

Comment: @Fred-ii- Indeed it has, but clearly it wasn't done... Otherwise we'd be have something specific to work from already ;)

Answer (score 0):

In order to expand an array occurance while inside a double quoted string you need to do this

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO product 
                (product_category , product_name) 
          VALUES('{$_POST['product_category']}','{$_POST['product_name']}')";
```

I also chnaged the name of the second field to `$_POST['product_name']` although that is just what I assume it would be called.

If you insist on not using prepared statement I would also, as a minimum add this

```
 $c = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['product_category']);
 $p = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['product_name']);

 $sql = "INSERT INTO product 
                (product_category , product_name) 
          VALUES('$c','$p')";
```

A safer way of doing this, to avoid SQL Injection would be to do

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO product 
                (product_category , product_name) VALUES(?, ?)";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $_POST['product_category'], $_POST['product_name']);

    mysqli_execute($stmt);

    .. .. .. 

} else {

    echo mysqli_error($conn);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure that in all `mysqli_` functions, the first parameter is the connection in procedural style. Yours has it in second. Otherwise a terrific answer!

Comment: @Qirel Thanks for picking that up. Changed all to be Proceedural as thats what OP is using and added, hopefully, all the connection params.